# Which one is best for hosting Jenkins - Ubuntu or Centos

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, centos, jenkins-cli

I am planning to install Jenkins on Linux Operating system. This server will be used as Build server. That will deploy code for node.js, angular and frontend apps. Considering performance, connecting to deployment servers remotely, build activities, which is best OS distribution for Jenkins. Ubuntu or CentOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we created our new Jenkins platform, we did a lot of tests and we decided to use CentOS (for the master and the slaves).

With CentOS, everything is running fine (Maven builds, some Javascript builds with Grunt and Node.js, ...). We have one master and 7 slaves (all running with CentOS).

Because we had to deliver some Debian packages, we did some tests with an Ubuntu slave.

We had some odd errors when building our Maven projects (with the same configuration than the CentOS boxes).

So finally, we decided to move on CentOS :)

Comment: We also decided to go with CentOS :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just the [main differences](https://www.futurehosting.com/blog/what-is-the-difference-between-centos-and-ubuntu-server/) are important. Regarding Jenkins there is no 'best' solution. Use the OS which you prefer.

Comment: Considering our build stuffs, we think CentOS would be the best. Thanks for the answer.